# Using an image as seekBar, with percentage

Tags: java, android, image, percentage

Considering to have this seek bar:

[image].

I want to do the same thing with my image. I want to select a part of this image from 0 to 100% and track this percentage.

For example, my original image (0% selected) is all grey. If I scroll a bit with my finger on the image, I can select for example 50% of the image and change the style color to evidence this change.

[image]

It is important for me to track this percentage because I need this to do other things on my personal project. How is it possible to do that with android? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is it possible to do that with android?` Yes, it is.

Comment: you know how? can you explain this to me, please? :) I have tried alone but without success at the moment.

Comment: The simplest way would be to have 2 overlayed images: one greyscaled and one in full color. then just cut away the portion of the colored image to show the underlying greyscale one - or the other way around. A rectangular mask would do the cutting job. Pretty much like in a photoediting software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try :)

Comment: I have a problem, I have to do this overlapping on an image that is inside a gridview. This because I have to do the same thing for different 3 images in this grid. I have found this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885527/how-to-fill-images-using-progressbar-in-android, but not work in my case.

Comment: That answer looks even simpler than what I had in mind, and I find it brilliant. Try working on a simplified project, to get the grasp over the technique. Then bring it into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that with android.

You can grey out an image with the code provided in [Graying out a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947921/graying-out-a-bufferedimage)
and you can get the touch position with the code provided in [How to get the Touch position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476779/how-to-get-the-touch-position-in-android) for any android app.
Now, if you know where your image is in the android app, lets say its between ymin=0 and ymax=640 and you know that the finger is at y=320, you can just divide y/ymax and get the percentage (50% or 0.5) of the image that is to be shown. Now you can grey out 50% of the image, et voila.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try :)

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you, so other users can find it more easily. If you came up with a working code sample, you could as could as well paste it as an answer to your own question and accept it.